# Custom jQuery Slider, Return to first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am practicing my jQuery skills by building a simple slider with 3 slides. There is an outer wrapper named slider wrapper that will have a  set width of 1400px and a height of 350px.

Inside this wrapper is an unordered list with its items floated left so that they display in a horizontal line. This whole unordered list is then animated to move left by 1400px, making the sliding motion. I am struggling to figure out how to return to the first slide without it looking terrible. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
        <style>
            * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            #sliderwrapper { width: 1400px; height: 350px; overflow: hidden; position:relative;}
            #sliderlist  { list-style: none; left: 0px; position:absolute; width:200000em;}
            .item { float: left; }

        </style>
    </head>


<body>

    <div id="sliderwrapper">

        <ul id="sliderlist">
            <li class="item 1">
                <div><img src="img1.png" /></div>
            </li>
            <li class="item 2">
                <div><img src="img2.png" /></div>
            </li>
            <li class="item 3">
                <div><img src="img3.png" /></div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    setInterval(slide, 1000);

    function slide() {

        var left = $('#sliderlist').css('left');
        left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);
        if (left <= -2800) {

            /*var slide = $('#sliderlist li:first');
            $('#sliderlist').children('li:first').remove();
            $('#sliderlist').append(slide);*/

            $('#sliderlist').css('left', '0px');
            $('#sliderlist').animate({ left: "-=1400" }, "slow", "swing");
        }
        else {
            $('#sliderlist').animate({ left: "-=1400" }, "slow", "swing");


        }
    }

});
```

Every 1 second the slide function, which animates the list to the left, is called. Once the last slide is displayed (at -2800px) the first slide needs to display again, however I want it to slide in the same the other ones do, rather than just appearing. If I set the left property to 0px then it just appears, and if I remove and append the items in a constant loop then the animation looks ugly.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f6rey710/

Comment: As you can see the first red slide just appears rather than sliding in, Im trying to find a way to have it slide in so the sliding looks constant

Comment: Let me take a look and see what I can come up with for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, here it is :

http://jsfiddle.net/f6rey710/1/

```
function slide() {

        var left = $('#sliderList').css('left');
        left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);
        if (left <= -800) {


            $('#sliderList').css('left', '-400px');
            var slide = $('#sliderList li:first');
            $('#sliderList').children('li:first').remove();
            $('#sliderList').append(slide);
            $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400px" }, "slow", "swing");

        }
        else {
            $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400" }, "slow", "swing");
        }
    }
```

Once the slide function has reached the end of the list elements in the list must be removed from the front of the queue and added to the end.

Answer (score 0):

What about animating it back to 0 with some animation as you are sliding your slides with animation. For example

```
if (left <= -800) {
    $('#sliderlist').animate({
        left: "0px"
    }, "slow", "swing");
} else {
    $('#sliderlist').animate({
        left: "-=400"
    }, "slow", "swing");
}
```

Animate from last slide to the first slide with some animation and it looks normal and this is the way many of jQuery sliders work.

Comment: I did try this and it does look quite nice but I'm trying to see if its possible to not have to slide through all the other slides to get back to the first one